# Backup MySQL database to google drive automatically

Tags: laravel, google-drive-api, cpanel, mysql-backup

I have an application in laravel and I want to take a backup of a MySQL database and upload it to my Google Drive automatically. Can you please guide me how can I do that without Third party API.

Comment: You can use laravel schedule, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://medium.com/@dennissmink/laravel-backup-database-to-your-google-drive-f4728a2b74bd

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup